# Adding element to dom doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom

When I try to add elements to my dom, they're not added, but when I console.log them, I do get a value `<th class="text-right" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></th>`

```
for(c=0; c<2; c++) {

console.log(document.getElementById('achats_table').tFoot.children[0].appendChild(document.createElement('th')));
    document.getElementById('achats_table').tFoot.children[0].appendChild(document.createElement('th'));
        }
```

Table HTML :

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

what am I doing wrong? how can I debug this? I get no console errors.

Comment: maybe they are added, but you just don't see them because they have nothing inside? you can try to add test values by storing the created elements in a var like this: `var th = document.createElement('th'); th.innerText = 'TEST'; document.getElementById('achats_table').tFoot.children[0].appendChild(th);`

Comment: @Kaddath I tried, it doesn't work, they're still not added.

Comment: You need to show the html. If that `tfoot` is empty, then it has no children and that code throws an error. Did you look in your console for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to add th elements to a currently blank tfoot? You could try this:

```
for(c=0; c<2; c++) {
    document.querySelector('#achats_table tfoot').appendChild(document.createElement('th'));
}
```